# Request to retrieve AssociatedBusinessUnits errors

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

Submit the following request:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <S:Header>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password
                    XXXX</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com"
            xmlns:ns2="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <ns2:RetrieveRequest>
                <ns2:ObjectType>AccountUser</ns2:ObjectType>
                <ns2:Properties>accountUserID</ns2:Properties>
                <ns2:Properties>UserID</ns2:Properties>
                <ns2:Properties>Roles</ns2:Properties>
                <ns2:Properties>Name</ns2:Properties>
                <ns2:Properties>Email</ns2:Properties>
                <ns2:Properties>ActiveFlag</ns2:Properties>
                <ns2:Properties>LastSuccessfulLogin</ns2:Properties>
                <ns2:Properties>ModifiedDate</ns2:Properties>
                <ns2:Properties>AssociatedBusinessUnits</ns2:Properties>
                <ns2:QueryAllAccounts>true</ns2:QueryAllAccounts>
                <ns2:Options/>
            </ns2:RetrieveRequest>
        </ns2:RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

And we're receiving the following error:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:99b28bcb-e304-49f9-a9bf-efcea217ea2e</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:e9556f64-fd5b-4141-9b14-a33726bdd863</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp
                wsu:Id="Timestamp-c2a8dd8a-d8b8-4135-acf2-c6074069672e">
                <wsu:Created>2016-01-28T14:25:13Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2016-01-28T14:30:13Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>Error: The Request Property(s)
                AssociatedBusinessUnits do not match with the fields of
                AccountUser retrieve</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>4707fd99-a8f2-43d8-bedf-83e995cba709</RequestID>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Cannot determine why we are getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the property is not available for retrieval from the object. Use Describe method to verify which properties are retrievable from the object.

Comment: note OP is about use of API to Exact Target